# Service Leaking with onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance

Tags: android

**Problem**
In my Activity, my bound Service leaks. But this only happens after the first screen orientation change. On the second (and following) changes of the screen orientation, the service does not leak. I can't unbind the service in `onPause` because the Service needs to run in foreground (if you unbind the service, foreground is stopped). Also, after rotation, the service still works (I can still call methods of the service).

**Environment**
I am developing for `midSdkVersion=8` and `targetSdkVersion=18` and I am using the `SupportActionBar`.

**Question**
Is there a way to prevent the Service to leak? I didn't find anything that helps, yet. Am I missing something?

**Code**
Relevant parts of MainActivity that extends `ActionBarActivity` from support library:

```
AbstractPlayerService mService;
private boolean mBound;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_layout);

    // Abstract Class that extends Service
    AbstractPlayerService service = (AbstractPlayerService) getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance();

    if(service != null) { 
        this.mService = service;
        mBound = true;
    }else{
        // init..
    }


@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    if(!mBound){
        // following line is line 170
        bindService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayerService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
}


public ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
        mService = null;
    }
};


@Override
public Object onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance () {
    return mService;
}
```

**LogCat**

```
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111): Activity de.malaka.player.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection de.malaka.player.MainActivity$1@4053fc20 that was originally bound here
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity de.malaka.player.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection de.malaka.player.MainActivity$1@4053fc20 that was originally bound here
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:938)
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:833)
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:932)
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:347)
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111):    at de.malaka.player.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:170)
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3817)
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1624)
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
11-27 15:42:31.992: E/ActivityThread(25111):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance` in [`FragmentActivity` source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java) you'll see that is calls `Activity#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` and that method is deprecated since level 13. In your case you can very well remove that method since you're anyway binding in `onStart` ... and you **MUST** unbind in `onStop`:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unbindService(mConnection);
}
```

According to [Service foreground documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground), there is no direct connection between running a service in the foreground and having it as bounded or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't find it right now (...) but I think there is a link between foreground and bound or not. To check that, I just added a piece of code that unbinds the service after a few seconds. Result: foreground stopped immediately. So the result of that would be restarting foreground after being bound again. Seems not right to me.. ?

Comment: And I am aware of deprecation and the deprecated method is ``onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`` not ``onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance``

Comment: Updated to reflect indirect calls from FragmentActivity to `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`

Comment: The service stops immediately because it's a bound service. And if there are no bindings, then the service will stop since that is how a [bound service is supposed to work](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html). So make your service non-bound.